# How to make word jumping and word deletion with the emacs pro essentials plugin behave like regular sublime word jumping and deletion

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to make alt+[direction]/alt+delete in behave like ctrl+[arrow]/ctrl+[delete] in regular sublime. The alt+delete jumps to much for my intuition, as does the other movements.

For example with deletion

`.class-` alt+delete will go to `.`

`.class-` ctrl+delete will go to `.class`

`f('hello', {` alt+delete will go to `f('`

`f('hello', {` ctrl+delete will go to `f('hello',`

I'd like to replace all alt+ behavior to ctrl+ behavior

Comment: What does the question have to do with Emacs? What is "emacs pro essentials"? The question seems unclear to me. Maybe the `emacs` tag should be removed?

Comment: This sort of seems like a question about key binding, but it's very unclear what key bindings are coming from where based on how you asked the question. Are you saying that in your current setup you want some keys to behave like other keys, or swap their functionality, or something else?

Comment: emacs pro essentials is the sublime text plugin to use emacs bindings. There isn't a tag for that plugin.

This is a question about how to remap the emacs bindings to behave like regular sublime binding for deleting and word jumping. I would like alt+b to behave like ctrl+left, same with alt+delete to behave like ctrl+delete etc.

Comment: So it's not a question about Emacs. It's a question about how, in Sublime, to remap Emacs-like keys to other keys.

Comment: yes you're right, sorry